# Xamarin Android App Crashing

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, genymotion

I am building an android app and using Genymotion emulator. this is my android version settings

[image]

this is my Genymotion virtual device settings

[image]

When I deploy through visual studio I am getting error that "Unfortunately the application has stopped"

[image]

Before deploying through visual studio, I checked the existing installed app in play store and it said app is not compatible with this version. now visual studio has deleted the installed version and I can;t access existing installed app.

I can see this information in output window of visual studio

```
> Android application is debugging.
02-14 02:32:58.289 E/libprocessgroup( 5238): failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10071: Read-only file system
02-14 02:32:58.289 W/Zygote  ( 5238): createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
02-14 02:32:58.289 I/art     ( 5238): Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-14 02:32:58.306 D/AndroidRuntime( 5238): Shutting down VM
02-14 02:32:58.306 E/AndroidRuntime( 5238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 02:32:58.306 E/AndroidRuntime( 5238): Process: [myappnamehere], PID: 5238
```

and this appears in device log

```
Error   4276    AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get 
provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_26 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4967)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4559)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: share stacktrace.

Comment: where can I find stacktrace?

Comment: visual studio output window information added.

Comment: screenshot removed and detail added

Comment: Can you try an Android emulator? Will you have the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if shared runtime is enabled. Just turn it off in your Android project settings. The problem is, that deploying get's slower :/ Don't forget to uninstall the app on the device manually (for all users (just moving to trash on the home screen isn't enough some times)).

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

[image: disabled shared runtime]

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue after an Visual Studio update from 16.09 to 16.10.

My Xamarin app that used to run without problem were crashing on real device whereas not crashing in emulator.

Modifying this android option to uncheck "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)" fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio version 16.7.5 and I was seeing this issue if I did not have "Generate one package (.apk) per selected ABI" selected. I've never had to use this setting before. I'm not sure what changed.

[image]